# Intrinsic Rand, what is the interval [0,1] or ]0,1] or [0,1[

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran, intrinsics

I use gfortran and I read in the doc (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RAND.html) :
*RAND(FLAG) returns a pseudo-random number from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1*

I wonder if 0 or 1 are included and I am surprised but I could not be able to find this answer. I think I have not used the right keywords.
To check it, I wrote this simple program :

```
program main

real :: x   
integer :: i

do i=1,1000000000
    x =rand()
    if (x == 0.0d0 .or. x == 1.0d0) then
        print *,i,x
    endif
enddo     
end program main
```

On the output, only 0.00000 is printed. 
So, could I conclude that the interval is [ 0.0 , 1.0 [ ? Or is it compiler, machine dependent, ... ? Is there a specification on rand() or not ?

Comment: It is compiler dependent for the specific reason that `rand` is a compiler specific extension. Is there a reason you prefer this over the Fortran standard `random_number`?

Comment: @francescalus. It is only for a simple test.. In my Real program, I use trng (Tina's random number generator). Thanks, I am going to use random_number.

Comment: gfortran's prng routines return values in the interval [0,1).  You should never get 1, and although it is theoretically possible to get 0, it is highly unlikely due to the period of the various generators used over the over years.

Comment: Just checked the source code.  Don't use `rand()`.  First comment after the LGPL is *Simple multiplicative congruent algorithm.  The period of this generator is approximately 2^31-1, which means that  it should not be used for anything serious.  The implementation here is based of an algorithm from  S.K. Park and K.W. Miller, Comm. ACM,  31, 1192-1201 (1988).  It is also provided solely for compatibility  with G77.*