# Logarithm of a random number

Tags: random, fortran, infinity

I wrote a fortran program to code this algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_A-ExpJ).
 It works on my computer. But after I asked these two questions ([Intrinsic Rand, what is the interval [0,1] or ]0,1] or [0,1[](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73680028/7462275) and [How far can we trust calculus with infinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73680732/7462275)), I think I could have a problem with `log(random())` because `call random_number(Xw); Xw = log(`**Xw**`)` is used.
Indeed, `random_number(Xw)` could return 0 and `log(0)=-infinity`.

Therefore, I plan to modify this line as follow `call random_number(Xw); Xw = log(`**1-Xw**`)` to change the random value interval from [0,1[ to ]0,1].

Is it a good idea or is there a best solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea. If you want your algorithm to be stable, you need to define bounds. your `log` function represents a priority, it can likely be as low as you want, but it must be a number. You can bind it to numerical precision:

```
program t
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none
     real(real64), parameter :: SAFE = exp(-0.5d0*huge(0.0_real64))

     print *, log(randoms_in_range(100,SAFE,1.0_real64))

   contains

      elemental real(real64) function in_range(f,low,hi) result(x)
         real(real64), intent(in) :: f ! in: [0:1]
         real(real64), intent(in) :: low,hi
         real(real64) :: frac
         frac = max(min(f,1.0_real64),0.0_real64)
         x = low+frac*(hi-low)
      end function in_range

      real(real64) function random_in_range(low,hi) result(x)
         real(real64), intent(in) :: low,hi
         call random_number(x)  ! [0,1]
         x = in_range(x,low,hi) ! [low,hi]
      end function random_in_range
      function randoms_in_range(n,low,hi) result(x)
         integer     , intent(in) :: n
         real(real64), intent(in) :: low,hi
         real(real64)             :: x(n)
         call random_number(x)  ! [0,1]
         x = in_range(x,low,hi) ! [low,hi]
      end function randoms_in_range
end program
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Why , in the `in_range` function, must `f`  be in  [0:1] (cf comment after dummy parameter declaration) ? If `f` is outside, `frac` will be inside this interval.

Comment: Yep, that's just a simple function that converts a number from the [0,1] range to a user-defined range. That's just an example, a better version would also check that the given range has `hi>=low`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

While mathematically it is true that if X is uniformly distributed on (the real interval) [0,1) then 1-X is uniformly distributed on (0,1], this does not particularly help you.

As noted in the description of the algorithm to which you link, the underlying assumption is that the base uniform distribution is over the interval (0,1). This is not the same as (0,1].

You can use rejection sampling to generate X uniformly over (0,1) from `random_number()` (which is [0,1)): throw away all zero occurrences.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Concerning (0,1) or (0,1], it is not so obvious for me. I read the original paper (ref 5 of wikipedia page) and others related papers (e.g. https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2019/06/11/faster-reservoir-sampling-by-waiting/). But, I could not find any document where the problem of discretization of random values is discussed.  I would have preferred to use a fortran code for this algorithm done by specialist of numerical analysis. But I could not find it.

Comment: Whether the domain for the logarithm is (0,1] or (0,1) is not much related to the discreteness but what the algorithm requires. (I haven't read the original papers to comment on that.) If the comment suggesting (0,1) is required is correct, use (0,1); if you can instead use (0,1] then 1-X can work but you can easily discard zeroes instead.